# C++ ostream << overloading problems

Tags: c++, iostream

We know that the fascinating class iostream is something too powerful.
it has overloded the insertion operator "<<" to take many datatypes:
ostream& operator(ostream&, int), 
ostream& operator(ostream&, char)...

we cannot instantiaate ostream: ostream print;
because ostream because its most CTORSs are "protected-socoped" (cannot be accessed from outside).

the only Constructor we can call is ostream(streambuf*) which takes a pointer to another class object ( class streambuf);

I just wanted to mess up with this class:

```
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

int operator << (ostream& out, int* x)
{
    out << "invoked!" << endl;
    cout << *x; // works well!
    cout << x; // normally works well and it prints the address that x points to but instead the program get in infinite loop or crushes!
    return *x;
}

int main()
{

    system("color 1f");

    int* pVal = new int(57);

    cout << *pVal << endl;

    int* pX = new int(7);
    cout << *pX << endl;

    cout << *pVal << ", " << *pX << endl;

    //cout << pVal << endl; // this doesn't work because my operator returns
    //int and not a reference to ostream.
    // and it is equal to: 0 << endl; which generates the same error
    cout << pVal; // this works


//  cout << endl << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I overloaded the insertion operator to take an lvalue as a reference to an ostream object and a pointer to int as rvalue, I popup a message inside my function to get sure that it is invoked.

Note that I intentionally overloaded it to return int value so that no one can write:

```
 out << pInt << *pInt << endl;
```

... but just:

```
out << pInt;
```

My problem, as you can see in the inline-comments above, is that whilst `cout << x`  normally works well, instead the program get in infinite loop or crushes!

```
return *x;
```

Can anyone explain why I am getting the error?

Comment: I wrote the problem. please pay it an attention.  cout << x; // normally works well and it prints the address that x points to but instead the program get in infinite loop or crushes!
    return *x;

Answer (score 1):

The problem hapens because if you just `cout << x`, it will call your overloaded function over and over. It never returns.

Here's the solution (cast x to void*)

```
int operator << (ostream& out, int* x)
{
    out << "invoked!" << endl;
    cout << *x; // works well!
    cout << (void*)x;
    return *x;
}
```

Comment: @KokuVanish if you're thankful for an answer deleting the whole question isn't an appropriate way to show it.